# Process/Send data at regular intervals in c++

Tags: c++, asynchronous, queue, intervals

I am processing lines from a file in C++.

```
line1
line2
line3...
```

From each line I construct a C++ object and put it in a queue.
What's the best way to dispatch these objects at regular intervals. For example, dispatch 100 objects per second etc?

Edit:
Objects don't have to be spaced evenly in the interval. As long as I send 100 objects per second, I can just send them immediately, then wait for the end of the second.

Comment: Calculate how long since the last time you processed an object, subtract it from 0.01 seconds, and `Sleep` (windows) / `usleep` (Linux) for that long

Comment: What should happen if your program for some reason was unable to send any data for 5 seconds (for example due to your computer being overloaded with other higher-priority tasks)? Should your program attempt to catch up by sending 600 objects at once, instead of only 100 objects? Or should it not attempt to catch up on the missing objects, and just continue attempting to send 100 objects per second, as soon as it gets to run again?

Comment: Could you please tell us more about what you are trying to accomplish, and why you want to time the object queuing this way? The method mentioned previously of using `Sleep()`/`usleep()` should work for what you describe so far, but if your goal is to manage [interprocess or inter-thread queuing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) then timing alone isn't adequate - you would need to apply some sort of mutual exclusion, message-passing, or switch to using a [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe).

Comment: Thank you for the ideas everyone. I need to deliver the objects/messages somewhere else but note sure yet how I am going to structure everything. The messages have to be delivered to and accessed by another process. Would I be able to write my code in a dll that can be accessed by both processes, or should I use something like zmq?

Comment: @codefast: I don't see how using the same DLL in both processes would help you transfer data between these processes. Since you appear to be using the Microsoft Windows platform, here is [an overview of interprocess communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) for that platform. I believe that a [pipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/pipes) may be best for what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No, this will run on linux so I meant to write .so but I mainly work on windows and I forgot. Maybe I don't understand shared libraries that well but I figured it was going to be straightforward to access objects from a shared library. My code will be a console app. I figured if i have the dispatch code in a shared lib, I can access that queue from another process, but I'm guessing I am wrong?

Comment: @codefast: I am not that familiar with shared libraries on Linux, so I may be wrong, but I do not see how using a shared library could help you solve the problem on Linux, either. I believe on Linux, it is common to use the function [`pipe`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) for interprocess communication.

Answer (score 0):

Code the logic into your queue. You have some sort of append method on your queue and a pop_front method. Well... The pop_front method can just be a bit smarter. It can throttle the passing out of work so it doesn't happen too quickly.

If necessary, your workers can tell the queue how quickly they're completing work as opposed to how quickly they're starting to do the work.